# IIS and HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized

Tags: iis

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC application to my local IIS (same computer) and I'm getting

```
HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized
```

after accessing the application through the browser.

I'm using forms authetication and on the development server it works fine.

I depolyed also a default ASP.NET MVC project and its working fine, so it must be something application related. Is there any way to get more information on this particular error ? Any log file or something. The message HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized isn't realy helpful.

Found some logs c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\ but there wasn't anything.

Tested on
Windows 7,IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check whether this is a permissions issue. Try this:

Select the web application returning `401 - Unauthorized`, and double-click the Authentication feature. Right-click the "Anonymous Authentication" provider and select edit. Switch the default anonymous user account ("IUSR") to ApplicationPoolIdentity. Now, right-click the web application in the left pane, select **Edit Permissions...**, select the **Security** tab, click Edit -> Add and add `IIS APPPOOL\NameOfAppPool`. Make sure the Application Pool Identity has read and execute permissions of the folder.

If you want to enable logging, check out this TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754631(WS.10).aspx